# Function currently changes each character but needs to change each word in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, output

I've got this piece of code

```
dict1={'h':'H', 'e':'E', 'l':'LL', 'o':'O', 'hello':'HELLO'}
def replfunc(match):
    return dict1[match.group(0)]

regex = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in dict1))
with open('/old.txt') as fin, open('/new.txt','w', encoding='UTF-8') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        fout.write(regex.sub(replfunc,line))
```

This piece of code currently reads in the old text file and matches characters in this file  with dict1 and outputs the new value in the new text file. I would like the above function to match words instead of characters how would i go about altering this?

For example if my old text file had the word 'hello' in it the output currently is 'HELLLLO' as it reads in characters but i would like the function to read that the word 'hello' is a key in the dictionary and print out 'HELLO'

Comment: "I would like the above function to match words instead of characters" Then why are there character-based keys in the mapping of potential replacements?

Answer (score 0):

The way you build the regex pattern causes the current issue. The shorter alternatives must be put after the longer ones.

You need to sort the `dict1` keys by length in the descending order:

```py
import re
def replfunc(match):
    return dict1[match.group(0)]

dict1={'h':'H', 'e':'E', 'l':'LL', 'o':'O', 'hello':'HELLO'}
regex = re.compile('|'.join(sorted([re.escape(x) for x in dict1], key=len, reverse=True)))

with open('/old.txt', 'r') as fin, open('/new.txt','w', encoding='utf-8') as fout:
    fout.write(regex.sub(replfunc,fin.read()))
```

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/7DUfSY):

```py
import re
def replfunc(match):
    return dict1[match.group(0)]

dict1={'h':'H', 'e':'E', 'l':'LL', 'o':'O', 'hello':'HELLO'}
regex = re.compile('|'.join(sorted([re.escape(x) for x in dict1], key=len, reverse=True)))
print(regex.sub(replfunc, 'hello world'))
# => HELLO wOrLLd
```